# MIT-scheme on M1 chip

Tags: mit-scheme

I'm following the suggestions from *teachyourselfcs.com* and Berkeley's cs61a appears in the list, more specifically the 2011 edition, in which *scheme* is used to teach several concepts.

I'm trying to install **scheme** on my computer, but I'm running into an error that seems to be related to my configuration.

I say that because I tried to install both [MIT Scheme](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/) as well as [STklos](https://stklos.net/) and run into the same error in the configure file:

```
./configure: line 8941: sort: No such file or directory
./configure: line 8938: sed: No such file or directory
```

The only thing that changes when I try to install one or the other is the number of lines in which the errors are found.

Does anyone know why am I getting this error?

Comment: MITScheme doc says flat out: "No support for Apple silicon: At this time, we are unable to support new macs using Apple's silicon (the M1 chip)." That means you, right? And I wouldn't expect STklos to be any different. Wouldn't it be better to ask for a Scheme that _does_ run on M1?

Comment: Hi @matt, I was actually able to install STklos on my computer right now. I ran into the error mentioned in this post as well but was able to go on and install it. I had to install two other libraries (libffi and pcre). My concern is that I ignored the two mentioned errors and I don't know what are the implications.

Comment: Then give that as an answer to your own question.

Comment: Might want to consider https://racket-lang.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to install STklos on Mac. I ignored the two errors mentioned in this question but had to install libffi and pcre.

After installing both I ran **./configure** and then **make**.